# Importing clob data into MySQL TEXT column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, import

I have written a PHP script to import a table from an Oracle server into a MySQL server. The importer works great except for the fact that the sole CLOB column, which I've made TEXT in MySQL, displays as NULL in every row. The data stored there is just large amounts of text, so nothing binary that would require the destination column be a BLOB.

Here is the relevant code I'm using in my script:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_row($oracle_result)) {  
      // Begin looping through all fields in current row
      for($i=0;$i<$num_fields;$i++) {               
          $this_field = $row[$i];       // Get data value for this field
          // $arFieldDefs holds field metadata
          $field_type = $arFieldDefs[$i]['type'];   // Get data type for this field
          $field_name = $arFieldDefs[$i]['name'];   // Get field name for this field

          if (is_null($this_field)) {
            //This field is NULL
            $this_field = "NULL";
          } else {
            // Field is not null, process its data type
            switch ($field_type) {
                case "NUMBER":
                    //str_replace(",", "", $this_field);    //Remove commas from number string
                    break;
                case "INT":
                    //str_replace(",", "", $this_field);    //Remove commas from number string
                    break;
                case "CHAR":
                    $this_field = "'" .addslashes($this_field) ."'";
                    break;
                case "VARCHAR2":
                    $this_field = "'" . addslashes($this_field) . "'";
                    break;
                case "DATE":
                    $this_field = "'" . $this_field . "'";
                    break;
                case "CLOB":
                    // Meaningful var name to remind us we now have an object of PHP class OCI-Lob
                    $clob_obj = $this_field;
                    // Tried read($clob_obj->size()) instead of load()
                    //   but result was the same
                    $field_contents = $clob_obj->load();
                    $this_field = "'" . $field_contents . "'";
                    break;
                default:
                    // $rec_num is the currently looped record number
                    echo "Bad Field Type '" .$field_type ."' in Field: '".$this_field ."' RecNum: " .$rec_num ."\n";
                    die;
            }
          }
          $value_string .= $this_field . ", ";      // Add comma and space after field value
      } // End FOR loop 
// Cleanup and finish:
// Strip trailing comma+space, put $value_string in parentheses,
// And loop back to build another row in the INSERT
} // End WHILE loop
```

I considered the possibility that I had to use LONGTEXT instead, but TEXT should suffice since the maximum number of characters in that column is roughly 10,000.

The MySQL version is 5.5.3, while the Oracle version is 11.2.0.3.0.

UPDATE - Here are a couple example inserts to show the actual data processed. The final column is the CLOB value that is MEDIUMTEXT on the destination table:
    `('00001206023', 'Notifications: SMB', NULL, NULL, 'SM001331700', 'XMLCSG', 1426176946, 'XMLCSG', NULL, 1426176946, '2015-03-12 16:15:47', 0, '28'), ('00001205439', 'Customer Experience', 'Customers will lose access to all services', NULL, 'CM001176996', 'tstins00', 1426176944, 'tstins00', NULL, 1426160634, '2015-03-12 16:15:46', 0, 'Customers will lose access to all services'),('00001206059', 'Required Tools', 'CustomerCenter-NorthDivision-Video', NULL, 'CM001177349', 'blassi001', 1426176976, 'blassi001', NULL, 1426176976, '2015-03-12 16:16:17', 0, 'CustomerCenter-NorthDivision-Video')`

The columns are as follows:

1. entry_id VARCHAR
2. element_name VARCHAR
3. short_data VARCHAR
4. element_data_old VARCHAR(4000)
5. sm_id VARCHAR
6. submitter VARCHAR
7. modified_date INT
8. last_modified_by VARCHAR
9. sort_order INT
10. create_date INT
11. replicated_date DATETIME
12. type INT
13. element_data MEDIUMTEXT [formerly BLOB, then LONGTEXT]

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_NAME (
  ENTRY_ID VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  ELEMENT_NAME VARCHAR(155) DEFAULT NULL,
  SHORT_DATA VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ELEMENT_DATA_OLD VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  SM_ID VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  SUBMITTER VARCHAR(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  MODIFIED_DATE INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LAST_MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  SORT_ORDER INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  CREATE_DATE INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  REPLICATED_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  TYPE INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  ELEMENT_DATA MEDIUMTEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ENTRY_ID),
  UNIQUE KEY MTN_ENTRYID_PK (ENTRY_ID),
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

Comment: Any change there are apostrophes in $field_contents?  `echo strlen($field_contents);` before the `break` in `case "CLOB":`.

Comment: Do you mean removing the apostrophes so the line reads: `$this_field = $field_contents`?

Comment: No.  Apostrophes inside `$field_contents` would cause trouble -- leading to something like `field2 = 'blah blah's blat'`  Notice the unbalanced apostrophes.

Comment: Yes, I have omitted the apostrophes and still receive the same result.

Comment: What did you get from `echo strlen($field_contents);` ?  I suspect that the CLOB was not read correctly.

Comment: I get various string lengths: 476, 2741, 2, 48, 1. It's all over the place. I'm going to output it to a file and see if I can sort to find the biggest length.

Comment: echo the INSERT statement after it is constructed.

Comment: Change LONGTEXT to MEDIUMTEXT.

Comment: I've changed LONGTEXT to MEDIUMTEXT, and echoing insert statements showed me the text of varying lengths (sometimes one sentence, other times a block of text with key/value pairs. It's worth noting that some characters appear as a vertical rectangle with lines through it, as if it's a character MySQL can't render).

In short, the values are being grabbed for insertion but aren't appearing in the destination table.

Comment: Can I see one of the shorter INSERTs; I am hoping to see some subtle problem that has escaped our notice.

Comment: Updated to show three differing examples of INSERTs.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` -- Something subtle is wrong; maybe that will show it.

Comment: Alas, I don't see any clues.  Unrelated:  Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`, this is redundant and can be dropped: `UNIQUE KEY MTN_ENTRYID_PK (ENTRY_ID)`.

Comment: Suggest you create another table and manually apply the INSERTs you captured.  Then interrogate the table to see if the TEXT field has NULLs or not.  If NULLs, you have a simple test case with which to write a bug report.  If not NULL, then there is some difference that we cannot see.

Comment: My senior team members are also confused - I'll try your suggestion regarding creating another table and seeing if manual inserts show the same result. Thank you for your insight on this issue, Rick.